# Running Spark on Mesos using --jars

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am trying to run a streaming spark wordcount on Mesos.  When I try deploying the code to the cluster and running, the jar files listed in --jars do not get copied into the sandbox.  If I am running in client-mode, they do get copied and my code runs.  Does --jars work with Mesos --deploy-mode cluster ?

I am running Apache Spark 2.0.0-preview and Mesos 0.28.

The mesos dispatcher from Spark is running along with my master and slave from Mesos.  Also, Zookeeper is running too.  The spark-submit call is below.

(running from $SPARK_HOME)

```
bin/spark-submit --class my.class.name --master mesos://<ip>:7077 \
--deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 1 --executor-memory 512M \
--total-executor-cores 1 --jars /full/path/jar1.jar,/full/path/jar2.jar \
project.jar parm1 parm2 parm3 parm4
```

This results in an error stating that it can not find a class in jar1.  Finally, I can run SparkPi from the examples jar using the same syntax as above (without --jars) and everything runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to have your jars in a accessible place for the executors, see

- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode

> Note that jars or python files that are passed to spark-submit should be URIs reachable by Mesos slaves, as the Spark driver doesn’t automatically upload local jars.

Comment: I forgot to mention everything is running local to my box.  I provide the full path to the jar in the --jars parm.  I tried using HDFS instead of just a file and it did not add them to the sandbox.

Comment: That doesn't matter in this case IMO. You'll have to upload the jars to a webserver I think. You're running in cluster mode, and then the quoted constraints should apply. You can upload the jars to a simple webserver (running as Docker Marathon app), e.g. https://github.com/tobilg/docker-mini-webserver and map a host folder containing the jars...